# Using ASP .NET MVC, how can I create a web page to display dynamic data from tests?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question or not but here goes:

At the moment I've put together a few applications at the place where I work that run a series of tests that check whether an application is working or not.  These tests return either okay, not okay, or needs attention (as well as a free text field that talks about extended details on the test that is being run).

This is exactly the display that I want. I mocked it up in ASP .NET MVC with bootstrap.

[image: What I want it to look like]

The idea is this:  When the circle on the outside does a full rotation (after a minute for instance), a table is checked in SQL for the outcome for that particular test.  If the test has failed, the box goes red with a cross.

I know enough MVC to build a controller that would respond with JSON, or whatever the heck else was needed, but I don't know how to actually piece it together.

I've started looking into things like Angular to accomplish this but I think it can be done easier. Thoughts?

EDIT: This would be the model that I would use:

```
 {'Test Group', 'Test Name', 'Test Result', 'Test Extended Information', 'Test Recurrence'}
```

which would contain this data

```
 {'xxxxx Robot Queue', 'xxxx Queue Depth', '1', 'Robot is okay', '30'}
```

The cards that displayed the tests, I don't actually have that code on me right now.  But I would be happy to see how it would work in the simplest of simple div's, and I think I could move forward if I knew how to do that :)

Comment: I can't lookup the actual project name at the moment, but I've used something in the past that basically works like XSL, but for JSON. That might work, depending on how complex your objects could be.

Comment: The objects will be simple.  Essentially (string)"Application Name", (integer)"Application Status", (string)"Application Extended Status".

Comment: In that case, XSL is probably overkill. This is the project I was referring to, anyway: https://github.com/twigkit/tempo. What you're trying to do seems easy enough with just jQuery or Zepto - is there something you're stuck on?

Comment: So, in MVC, I know I could construct a view with a List with tests in it, as well as how they went.  And then I could iterate over that list with something like a foreach loop.  But that fires once and then the page doesn't refresh.  I know in jquery I could iterate over a collection of div's or equivalent, but I guess the question is, how do I make a certain div refresh every n seconds with a new result in it?  The new result will be whether the test was successful or not.

Comment: The other thing is that test 1 might refresh every 60 seconds, while test 2 might refresh every 2 minutes.  How long each test should wait before checking the results again will vary from test to test, and the amount of time that should be waited will be stored in a database

Comment: I was going to suggest you add something to your model, which your last comment covers. As for the first, I'd have to ask that you first amend your question to include, say, the model you'll likely use, and the markup to generate something similar to your mockup, at a minimum. With that, I would be willing to add an example of using `setInterval` to poll your controller for an item's status. Otherwise: use jQuery/Zepto's .each() function to create a separate setInterval function, and do your polling inside that.

Comment: Hey, I've edited the original question :) @TiesonT.